# Embed Adobe Air/Flex application inside a standard iOS application

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I have a native (Obj-C, standard Xcode project) application and I'd like to integrate a partners iOS application (or specifically, it's functionality) into it as just another view in my application.   The problem is that their application is a Flex/Air app.  I really don't understand the Adobe compilation process  on how it gets from a bunch of flex code down to an IPA.  I don't see intermediate projects, shared objects, etc on the disk to produce that IPA.  It looks like it doesn't rely on the Apple tool chain... as I understand it, you can produce the IPA on Windows as well.

Is there any way to build that Flex app in such a way that I can import it into Xcode so I can link against it and use it as a library from within my application?

While I specifically used iOS as an example since that is the most important platform, we'll want to apply this solution to our respective Android and Blackberry 6 apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot embed an application within another application.  This is true for *all* applications.  Only thing you could do is get the swf of your partner's code and embed that into an Air application, but since you're not using Actionscript/Flex, it won't be possible.

Only other way would be to have an app link to the other application.

Comment: I was under the impression that I could link against any object or shared object I wanted to within Xcode iOS projects.

Comment: You can link to shared objects (data) without issues I think, but your original question was about "integrating a partner's application into just another view", which isn't possible.

Comment: Sorry, I think of an application as it's functionality, not the .app or executable containers.

Comment: hi @Trey did you find any solution for the same? if yes Please provide the solution i am also trying the same thing.

Comment: Nope sorry.  We'll be having our partner create a white labeled app for us instead.